# How to change only one function of CSS transform property w/ multiple functions?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div, and the css is like below

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-404.747px);
}
```

and now, I want use jQuery to change the transform property to

```
transfrom: rotateY(-40deg) translateZ(-404.747px);
```

if I use

```
$('.container').css('transform', 'rotateY(-40deg) translateZ(-404.747px)');
```

then 'translateZ(-404.747px)' will take action again.
So, my question is how can I change the value of rotateY(), without change the 'translateZ()' ?

Comment: Well I am not sure about the real implementation BUT what you could do without having a major issue is to wrap another element around it and then apply the rotateY - if that is sufficient for you.

Comment: just apply rotateY(-40deg) on container class....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container remove"></div>

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; 
}

.add{
transfrom: rotateY(-40deg) translateZ(-404.747px);
}

.remove{
transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-404.747px);
}

$('.container').removeclass('remove');
$('.container').addclass('add');
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I found the  'translateZ(-404.747px)' will not take action agian, if I use $('.container').css('transform', 'rotateY(-40deg) translateZ(-404.747px)'); the real problem is the order of rotateY and translateZ will achieve different results. So I swap these two property, the issue solved.

Comment: @kebenhu, please provide your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

just plop it in the style attr!

```
$('.container').css('transform', 'rotateY(-40deg)');
```